# What does "Slaves with white collars" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Fight Club (1999)*, Tyler motivates fight club:

> Tyler: Goddamn it, an entire generation pumping gas. Waiting tables.
> **Slaves with white collars**. Advertising has us chasing cars and
> clothes. Working jobs we hate so we can buy shit we don't need.

What does "Slaves with white collars" mean?
[This](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58162/could-you-explain-white-collar-in-simple-english) didn't helped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"White collar" refers to people working in office jobs (contrasted with "blue collar": people who work in manual jobs.  (Typical office wear includes a white shirt, but manual workers tend to wear blue or coloured overalls or shirts which don't show dirt so easily).

Tyler is speaking hyperbolically:  He is saying that office workers are slaves, that they have no freedom. Tyler seems to be mixing the standard blue/white shirt collar metaphor a metaphor for a slave's iron collar.

Comment: It might go deeper.  Tyler seems to be mixing the standard blue/white shirt collar metaphor with the metaphor of a slave's collar.  "Working jobs we hate so we can buy shirts [with collars that] we don't need" could imply the entire generation *enslaving itself* under the influence of advertising.  Sometimes, a mixed metaphor isn't a bad thing.